# Trying to create an index using imakidx but idx file is empty

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I am using the package BL-OSCOLA which is a legal citation package. I want to create an index which is a table of cases (so it doesn't need to index what page these appear on, I just need to be able to show my extensive list of cases, categorised according to jurisdiction). I have followed the instructions from the Oscola package but the idx file and ind files are being created as empty (idx shows no entries, and nothing is written in the ind file) so no index is created. When I check the folder, all the indexed items have been sent to a trash file instead. What am I doing wrong? (and I'm a nooby so please explain it like you would to a 10 year old).

I run pdflatex, then biber, then pdflatex, then makeindex - but that's where it stops with nothing! (So even a final run of pdflatex makes no difference) I've also tried it without biber, still no luck.

Here is my "main" texfile:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,a4paper,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, indexing=cite]{biblatex}   
%indexing=cite is necessary for the table of cases
\addbibresource{testbiblio.bib} %necessary for Oscola
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes} %necessary for Oscola

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=intcases, title={Table of Cases from International Tribunals}]

%DeclareIndexAssociation "hooks" the citations to the index name above. The first 
%variable is the keyword in my bib file
\DeclareIndexAssociation{ICTY}{intcases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{ICC}{intcases}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget elit gravida,
pharetra mauris at, malesuada dui. Sed vitae tortor ante. Quisque sollicitudin 
accumsan nulla sit amet mattis.\footcite{Tadic} Nam non malesuada nisl. Aliquam erat 
volutpat.\footcites{Vasiljevic}{Banda} In eu vulputate sem, in sagittis arcu. Nullam 
fringilla libero non nisi aliquam, eget pulvinar arcu pulvinar. Ut tristique 
ullamcorper nisl, vitae cursus nulla varius vel. Proin non rhoncus 
risus.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment}


\printindex[intcases]

\end{document}
```

Here is my bib file (please note, these are cases, so all the information here is necessary for proper citation):

```
@jurisdiction{AlBashirIndictment,
title = {Public Redacted Version of Prosecutor's Application for Warrant of Arrest 
under Art. 58},
date = {2008-09-12},
number = {ICC-02/05-157},
court = {ICC Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords= {ICC},
}

@jurisdiction{Banda,
title = {The Prosecutor v Banda and Jerbo},
date = {2011-03-07},
number = {ICC--02/05-03/09-121-Conf-Corr},
court = {ICC Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords= {ICC},
}

@jurisdiction{Tadic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Dusko Tadi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
date = {1999-07-15},
number = {IT-94-1-A},
court = {ICTY Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords= {ICTY}
}

@jurisdiction{Vasiljevic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Mitar Vasiljevi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
date = {2004-02-25},
number = {IT-98-32-A},
court = {ICTY Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
keywords = {ICTY}
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the field `tabulate={intcases}` if you want to introduce a new case index type named `intcases`, see p. 16 of the current documentation to `oscola`.

I have updated the bibliography file for this feature and changed the traditional `makeindex` to `splitindex`, as recommended in the manual too.

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,a4paper,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, indexing=cite]{biblatex}   
%indexing=cite is necessary for the table of cases
\addbibresource{testbiblio.bib} %necessary for Oscola

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes} %necessary for Oscola

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

%DeclareIndexAssociation "hooks" the citations to the index name above. The first 
%variable is the keyword in my bib file

\DeclareIndexAssociation{ICC}{intcases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{ICTY}{intcases}

\makeindex[name=intcases, title={Table of Cases from International Tribunals}]


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget elit gravida,
pharetra mauris at, malesuada dui. Sed vitae tortor ante. Quisque sollicitudin 
accumsan nulla sit amet mattis.\footcite{Tadic} Nam non malesuada nisl. Aliquam erat 
volutpat.\footcites{Vasiljevic}{Banda} In eu vulputate sem, in sagittis arcu. Nullam 
fringilla libero non nisi aliquam, eget pulvinar arcu pulvinar. Ut tristique 
ullamcorper nisl, vitae cursus nulla varius vel. Proin non rhoncus 
risus.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment}


\printindex[intcases]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**testbiblio.bib**

```
@jurisdiction{AlBashirIndictment,
title = {Public Redacted Version of Prosecutor's Application for Warrant of Arrest 
under Art. 58},
date = {2008-09-12},
number = {ICC-02/05-157},
court = {ICC Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate={intcases},
keywords= {ICC},
}

@jurisdiction{Banda,
title = {The Prosecutor v Banda and Jerbo},
date = {2011-03-07},
number = {ICC--02/05-03/09-121-Conf-Corr},
court = {ICC Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate={intcases},
keywords= {ICC},
}

@jurisdiction{Tadic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Dusko Tadi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
date = {1999-07-15},
number = {IT-94-1-A},
court = {ICTY Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate={intcases},
keywords= {ICTY},
}

@jurisdiction{Vasiljevic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Mitar Vasiljevi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
date = {2004-02-25},
number = {IT-98-32-A},
court = {ICTY Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate={intcases},
keywords = {ICTY},
}
```

[image]